# Strip Values From Post in Nested Loop

Tags: php, forms, loops, foreach

I have a function that is used for dynamically building an update query that works by having a manually created form with fields that match the names of the table columns, then building the query based on the field names and values being submitted. However I have come across an instance where certain posted fields must be filtered out. I can do it easily if done manually but I am trying to make it work when the number of columns to remove, which are fed in as an array, are not necessarily known in advance.

For example, if I use this in place of one of the foreach loops below, it works:

```
$FieldName = array_values($Date1Name);
// Remove $Date1Name submit values
if ($key == $FieldName[1]) continue;
if ($key == $FieldName[2]) continue;
if ($key == $FieldName[3]) continue;
```

but I am trying to do it dynamically similar to the following. Note that in this case, the first value of the array must not be removed as it is the actual field name but in the second foreach loop, all are to be removed. Any ideas?

```
function formProcess($ID,$DBName,$TableName,$PassName,$Date1Name,$Date2Name,$RemoveFields,$insertGoTo) {
    $Values = array();
    // Update record
    if (isset($_POST["update"])) :
        unset($_POST['update']);
        foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value ) :

            if (is_array($Date1Name)) :
                // ARRAY EXAMPLE
                //$Date1Name = array("StartDate","month1","day1","year1");
                $Field1Name = array_values($Date1Name);

                foreach($Date1Name as $keyrm) :
                    if ($keyrm !== 0 && $key == $Field1Name) continue;
                endforeach;
            endif;

            if (is_array($RemoveFields)) :
                // Remove certain fields from POST using $RemoveFields array values
                // ARRAY EXAMPLE
                //$RemoveFields = array("ID","EndName");
                $FieldRemoved = array_values($RemoveFields);

                foreach($RemoveFields as $keyrm) :
                    if ($keyrm == $FieldRemoved) continue;
                endforeach;
            endif;

            $Values[] = "`$key`=".isNull($value, $DBName);
        endforeach;
        $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE $TableName SET ".implode(",",$Values)
                    ." WHERE ID='".intval($ID)."'";
        DBConnect($sqlUpdate, "Update", $DBName);
        if ($insertGoTo) :
            Redirect(sprintf('%s', $insertGoTo."?ID=".intval($ID)));
        endif;
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar task in the past, perhaps it will give you some idea(s). This is assuming you are using `mysql`, if not, the filter may need some degree of manual handling.

1) Create a function that will extract the fields from the table. I have a class that I am feeding in which is labeled as `$db`. It will run my queries and return associative arrays:

```
function getFields($table,$db)
    {
        # Run the "describe table" query
        $fields =   $db->query("describe {$table}")->getResults();
        # Extract just the field names from the rows
        foreach($fields as $row) {
            $val[]  =   $row['Field'];
        }
        # Send back the field names
        return $val;
    }
```

Here is what the above function would return on a simple `user` table:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ID
    [1] => username
    [2] => password
    [3] => first_name
    [4] => last_name
    [5] => email
    [6] => country
    [7] => usergroup
    [8] => user_status
    [9] => timestamp
)
```

2) Next create the filtering function. I would send back a bind array as well, I am using `PDO` here as my end database, not sure which library you are using.

```
function filterArray($array,$filter = array())
    {
        $bind   =   
        $cols   =   array();

        if(!is_array($filter))
            $filter =   array();

        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if(!empty($filter) && !in_array($key, $filter))
                continue;
            $bKey           =   ":{$key}";
            $bind[$bKey]    =   $value;
            $cols[]         =   $key;
        }

        return array(
            'columns'=>$cols,
            'bind' => $bind
        );
    }
```

3) Make the update function. I have made it simple, you can make it as complex as you need it.

```
# The first is the filtered array, the $where is which key to update on,
# the $table is obvious, the $op is the operator which could be substituted for
# LIKE or !=
function getUpdateStatement($array,$where,$table,$op = '=')
    {
        # Start off the statement
        $sql['update'][]    =   "UPDATE {$table} SET";
        # Combine and loop the keys/values and assign the WHERE anchor as well
        foreach(array_combine($array['columns'],array_keys($array['bind'])) as $col => $bind) {
            if($col == $where)
                $sql['where'][] =   "WHERE `{$col}` {$op} {$bind}";
            else
                $sql['cols'][]  =   "`{$col}` = {$bind}";
        }
        # Create the statement from the parts
        $statement  =   implode(' ',$sql['update']).' '.implode(", ",$sql['cols']).' '.implode(" AND ",$sql['where']);
        # Send back statement
        return $statement;
    }
```

To use:

```
# Get all the columns from the table
$filter = getFields('users',$queryEngine);
# Let's pretend the is a actually your $_POST array...
$POST   =   array(
    'ID' => 123,
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'email' => 'test@best.com',
    'update' => 'SAVE',
    'action' => 'update_my_stuff',
    'token' => 'aB23As753hedD6baC213Dsae4'
);
# Create the filtered array
$filtered = filterArray($POST,$filter);
# Create the statement
echo getUpdateStatement($filtered,'ID','user');
```

This above statement will read:

```
UPDATE users SET `first_name` = :first_name, `last_name` = :last_name, `email` = :email WHERE `ID` = :ID
```

Remember the bind values are in the `$filtered['bind']` array. Hopefully this is what you are kind of looking for or that it will maybe give you some ideas.

Comment: One of my sites has dynamic forms which are set up as values from a couple MySQL tables rather than being fetched directly from the table structure while this one has semi-dynamic forms. That is, the form is created manually, then submits for the function to process which it already does quite nicely so no MySQL connectivity issues involved. But there are some fields to not process and that is where I am having the trouble and you may have given some clues I need to sort it out, thank you! I've not done this sort of thing before so appreciate the tips.

Comment: Ok, so then all you need to do is have a way (manual or what-have-you) to create the filtering array so you end up with a list of columns to allow (as formatted in point one of my answer).

Comment: I had only a few minutes to play with this but plugged into my function the filterArray() and getUpdateStatement() posted above to see what they would do. So far it looks promising although it gives all the fields to NOT use and there are no values. I'll be gone for a week but tomorrow before I go I'll try to analyze to see what is needed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. You tried some of the functions?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I hit Enter and it submitted while I was still writing. Should be corrected now.

Comment: To your comments: *"So far it looks promising although it gives all the fields to NOT use"* -> The filter array (should be made up of column names) are what you want to keep and it throws away any that are not in the filter. *"and there are no values."* Values will come from the `$filtered['bind']` after you create the filtered array using the `filterArray()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Working now and updated to handle Insert, Update and Delete operations. I decided that I couldn't have separate functions for the update and insert query building due to the need for some special field processing so I moved the functionality back into the main formProcess() function. I did need to filter out certain fields rather than say which fields to keep so came up with a way to do that using a combination of array_diff_key() and array_flip() which seems to do the trick. This provides an array of all the fields to be processed. The main reason for this is to filter out day, month and year selectors, then process them into a single field:

*$filteredarray = array_diff_key($_POST, array_flip($RemoveFields));*

I am sure that some of the programmers here can really simplify this code but here it is as it now stands with some annotations to say what does what. I hope it helps someone!

```
function formProcess($ID,$DBName,$TableName,$PassName,$Date1Name,$Date2Name,$RemoveFields,$insertGoTo) {
    // Insert record
    if (isset($_POST["insert"])) :
        unset($_POST["insert"]);
        // Remove unneeded fields from $RemoveFields variable
        if (!is_array($RemoveFields)) $RemoveFields = array($RemoveFields);
        $filteredarray = array_diff_key($_POST, array_flip($RemoveFields));
        // Build the INSERT query
        foreach($filteredarray as $col => $val) :
            // Process Password field
            if ($PassName) :
                // Encode password field
                if ($col == $PassName && $val != "") $val=md5($val);
                // If no changes, save original password
                if ($col == $PassName && $val == "") continue;
            endif;
            // Process Date/Time fields using custom dateProcess()
            if (is_array($Date1Name)) :
                $pieces1 = $Date1Name;
                if ($col == $pieces1[0]) $val = dateProcess($Date1Name);
            endif;
            if (is_array($Date2Name)) :
                $pieces2 = $Date2Name;
                if ($col == $pieces2[0]) $val = dateProcess($Date2Name);
            endif;
            $Fields[] = "`$col`";
            $Values[] = isNull($val, $DBName);
        endforeach;

        $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO $TableName (".implode(",",$Fields).") 
                      VALUES (".implode(",",$Values).")";

        // Custom function to process the INSERT query
        $InsertID = DBConnect($sqlInsert, "Insert", $DBName);
        if ($insertGoTo) :
            Redirect(sprintf('%s', $insertGoTo."?ID=".intval($InsertID)));
        endif;
    // Update record
    elseif (isset($_POST["update"])) :
        unset($_POST['update']);
        // Remove unneeded fields using array $RemoveFields variable
        if (!is_array($RemoveFields)) $RemoveFields = array($RemoveFields);
        $filteredarray = array_diff_key($_POST, array_flip($RemoveFields));
        // Build the UPDATE query
        $count = 0;
        $fields = '';
        $Where = '';
        foreach($filteredarray as $col => $val) :
            if ($count++ != 0 && $col != "ID") $fields .= ', ';
            if ($col == "ID") :
                $Where = " WHERE `$col` = " . intval($val);
            else :
                // Process Password field
                if ($PassName) :
                    // Encode password field
                    if ($col == $PassName && $val != "") $val=md5($val);
                    // If no changes, save original password
                    if ($col == $PassName && $val == "") continue;
                endif;
                // Process Date/Time fields
                if (is_array($Date1Name)) :
                    $pieces1 = $Date1Name;
                    // Process first Date/Time field using custom function
                    if ($col == $pieces1[0]) $val = dateProcess($Date1Name);
                endif;
                if (is_array($Date2Name)) :
                    $pieces2 = $Date2Name;
                    // Process second Date/Time field using custom function
                    if ($col == $pieces2[0]) $val = dateProcess($Date2Name);
                endif;
                // Build the UPDATE query
                $val = isNull($val, $DBName);
                $fields .= "`$col` = $val";
            endif;
        endforeach;

        $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE $TableName SET $fields $Where";

        // Custom function to process the INSERT query
        DBConnect($sqlUpdate, "Update", $DBName);
        if ($insertGoTo) :
            Redirect(sprintf('%s', $insertGoTo."?ID=".intval($ID)));
        endif;
    // Delete record
    elseif (isset($_POST["delete"])) :
        // Build the DELETE query
        $sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM $TableName WHERE ID=".intval($ID);
        // Custom function to process the DELETE query
        DBConnect($sqlDelete, "Delete", $DBName);
        if ($insertGoTo) :
            Redirect(sprintf('%s', $insertGoTo));
        endif;
    elseif (isset($_POST["clear"])) : // NOT CURRENTLY FUNCTIONAL
        foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) :
            if ($key == 'clear') continue;
            if (trim($key)) :
                $key = "";
                $value = "";
            endif;
            if (isset($_POST[$key])) :
                unset($key);
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Your INSERT and UPDATE query strings are insecure / vulnerable to injection attacks because you are directly writing user-supplied data into your queries.  To fix this issue, I recommend `mysqli` or `pdo` prepared statements with placeholders.